# TS: Array to object type conversion

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-inference, type-assertion

I have the following value:

```
const MY_CONST = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "ITEM_1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "ITEM_2"
  }
] as const;
```

I would like to reduce the value to a typed object, staying in the order as it was in MY_CONST

```
type ConvertedConst = {
    1: "ITEM_1";
    2: "ITEM_2";
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
type MyConstItem = (typeof MY_CONST)[number];
type ConvertedConst = Record<MyConstItem["id"], MyConstItem["name"]>;

const converted = MY_CONST.reduce<ConvertedConst>((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.id] = curr.name;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

But the type ends up being:

```
type ConvertedConst = {
    1: "ITEM_1" | "ITEM_2";
    2: "ITEM_1" | "ITEM_2";
}
```

I presume some generic approach should be taken but I'm lost a little bit. Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m0z8Gw) solve your problem? if Yes I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Although JavaScript object properties have order now, I don't think TypeScript object type properties do. But beware that the order of JavaScript object properties may surprise you and it's generally best **not** to rely on it (even if you know the rules). For instance, if your starting point had the `id: 2` before the `id: 1`, the order of the JavaScript properties wouldn't match, because that order requires that a property called `1` must appear before a property called `2`.

Comment: Btw, `const converted = Object.fromEntries(MY_CONST.map(item => [item.id, item.name])) as ConvertedConst`

Comment: @Bergi It’s shorter and more readable approach but it makes 2 iterations :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired type can be achieved by mapping through the elements of the array as follows:

```
type ConvertedConst = {
  [K in MyConst[number] as K['id']]: K['name'];
};
```

The crucial part is `as K['id']`. By this [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as), we are telling typescript to use `K['id']` as a key and the value is pretty straightforward: `K['name']`.

```
type MyConst = typeof MY_CONST;

// type ConvertedConst = {
//   1: "ITEM_1";
//   2: "ITEM_2";
// }
type ConvertedConst = {
  [K in MyConst[number] as K['id']]: K['name'];
};
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/m0z8Gw)

Comment: These are called *mapped types* and the use of `as` is called [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).